# I can't clone git repository .../info/refs not valid

Tags: git

So you can help me? I can't clone git repository:

** My command **

```
§ git clone https://github.com/micaelandre/micaelandre.github.io.git
```

and I can see this error :

**GIT OUTPUT**

```
fatal error: https://github.com/micaelandre/micaelandre.github.io.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone a repository with `HTTPS` or `SSH`, you should configure SSH in your local & remote to use `SSH`.

```
git clone https://github.com/micaelandre/micaelandre.github.io.git
```

or if you enable ssh

```
git clone git@github.com:micaelandre/micaelandre.github.io.git
```

Comment: So, my command is git clone https://github.com/micaelandre/micaelandre.github.io.git and my output is : fatal error: https://github.com/micaelandre/micaelandre.github.io.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

Comment: Did you create the repository first in Github? or create the repository in local?

Comment: I have create repository in github, you can check on this url : https://github.com/micaelandre/micaelandre.github.io

Comment: I don't push the repository, frist I clone de github repository

Comment: Try to clone the repository to any other folder path. Just now I cloned your repository & it's working fine for me

Comment: take me an example, please: I try git  update-server-info and result is thisfatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: Did you try to clone the repository to a different location?

Comment: Can I create a sub-path folder and clone my repository in the new path-folder

Comment: Navigate to another location, Eg-: Desktop & try to clone again.

Comment: I change de repository to /home/Documents and I try clone again but I obtain the same result

Answer (score 1):

my issue was that the git client was too old

I'm using jenkins + git scm plugin to clone my git repo and I got the error

> stderr: error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while
>   accessing https://github.com/owner/repo.git/info/refs

I opened the link with my error and I saw the message:

> Please upgrade your git client. GitHub.com no longer supports git over
>   dumb-http:
>   https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days

I have centos 6.5 and when I tried to update my git client I got from the yum repositories only the git client version 1.7.1

so in order to get the latest git client (for me it was 2.4.4) I had to use this [guide](https://blacksaildivision.com/git-latest-version-centos)

*there are many guides on the internet for this

and than I could clone my git repo successfully

Answer (score 1):

The **fatal error: XXX is this a git repository?** can be related with multiple causes from server side, but if we are 100% sure that the repository is ok (i.e. you have cloned from other machines) then you are facing problems with the host resolution.

1. Check your proxy settings (as author advices).

   > git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
   >    git config --global https.proxy https://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
   >    git config http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
   >    git config https.proxy https://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
2. (This was my case) Set up host mapping within /etc/hosts or c:\windows...\etc\hosts (depending on your OS) to force the right host<->IP resolution. (Useful if your host is inside an VPN).
3. Check other possible problems (ignore ssl certs, check connection, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I was using older version (`2.7.0`) of git client. After upgrading to newer version (`2.18.0`) this gets resolved.